# evaluating $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\left(-\frac{1}{5}\right)^{n-1}$

Tags: summation

Evaluate with justification $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\left(-\frac{1}{5}\right)^{n-1}$$

I'm not quite sure how to evaluate this sum, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

Consider

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n x^{n-1}=\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty  x^{n}\right)'$$  When done, make $x=-\frac 15$.

Comment: im not sure I understand where to go from there

Comment: @Duncan. What is the derivative of $x^n$ ?

Comment: it's nx^n-1, but Im not sure how I go about evaluating the sum with this information